# How to force app chooser on system default voice commands in android wear?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I am working on an Android wear application, which has to launch on saying command "start run" which is one of android wear default commands.Hence, the problem is there are other applications which are listening to the same command intent.The Android wear OS considers whichever app the user chooses for first time as default app to open from next time onwards. Instead, I would like to show an app chooser intent every time "start run" command is prompted.Is there any way to do this? do suggest.